# How do I write the numeric vector in R

Tags: r

How do I write the numeric vector `(3,4,5,30,40,50,. . .,30000,40000,50000)` in R?
I have tried `rep(3:5, 4)*10^(0:4)` but it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: `(3:5)*10^(rep(0:4, each = 3))`

Comment: `c(outer(3:5, 10^(0:4)))`

Comment: @d.b Thanks for the answer

Comment: `c(outer(3:5, 0:4, function(x, y) x*10^y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
as.numeric(c("-.1"," 2.7 ","B")) # (-0.1, 2.7, NA)  +  warning
as.numeric(factor(5:10))
```